# What do the return values of Comparable.compareTo mean in Java?

Tags: java, comparable

What is the difference between returning `0`, returning `1` and returning `-1` in [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) in Java?

Comment: compareTo can also return -2, or 42, though.

Comment: Do try the Javadoc some time.

Comment: if you have trouble remembering, (like i do), i simply imagine it as being a number subtraction operation `a-b` if `a` is bigger, the result is positive (+1) else, if `b` is bigger the result is negative...if they're equal its `0`

Comment: @Thilo can you explain more about that ?

Answer (score 102):

### Official Definition

From the reference docs of [Comparable.compareTo(T)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29):

> Compares this object with the
>   specified object for order. Returns a
>   negative integer, zero, or a positive
>   integer as this object is less than,
>   equal to, or greater than the
>   specified object.
>
> The implementor must ensure
>   sgn(x.compareTo(y)) ==
>   -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y. (This implies that x.compareTo(y) must
>   throw an exception iff y.compareTo(x)
>   throws an exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that
>   the relation is transitive:
>   (x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0)
>   implies x.compareTo(z)>0.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure
>   that x.compareTo(y)==0 implies that
>   sgn(x.compareTo(z)) ==
>   sgn(y.compareTo(z)), for all z.
>
> It is strongly recommended, but not
>   strictly required that
>   (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)).
>   Generally speaking, any class that
>   implements the Comparable interface
>   and violates this condition should
>   clearly indicate this fact. The
>   recommended language is "Note: this
>   class has a natural ordering that is
>   inconsistent with equals."
>
> In the foregoing description, the
>   notation sgn(expression) designates
>   the mathematical signum function,
>   which is defined to return one of -1,
>   0, or 1 according to whether the value
>   of expression is negative, zero or
>   positive.

### My Version

In short:

```
this.compareTo(that)
```

returns

- **a negative int** if this < that
- **0** if this == that
- **a positive int** if this > that

where the implementation of this method determines the actual semantics of `<` `>` and `==` (I don't mean `==` in the sense of java's object identity operator)

### Examples

```
"abc".compareTo("def")
```

will yield something smaller than 0 as `abc` is alphabetically before `def`.

```
Integer.valueOf(2).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(1))
```

will yield something larger than 0 because 2 is larger than 1.

### Some additional points

**Note:** It is good practice for a class that implements Comparable to declare the semantics of it's compareTo() method in the javadocs.

**Note:** you should read at least one of the following:

- the [Object Ordering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) section of
  the Collection Trail in the Sun Java
  Tutorial
- [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective) by
  Joshua Bloch, especially item 12:
  *Consider implementing Comparable*
- [Java Generics and Collections](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527754) by
  Maurice Naftalin, Philip Wadler, chapter 3.1: *Comparable*

**Warning:** you should never rely on the return values of compareTo being `-1`, `0` and `1`. You should always test for `x < 0`, `x == 0`, `x > 0`, respectively.

Comment: Remember, in the documentation they talk about `sgn()`, not directly -1 and 1. You should add this to your short version.

Comment: I know. I prefer real language to mathematical mumbo-jumbo (boy am I glad that you can't downvote comments :-)), so I wrote *-1 (or smaller)* and *1 (or larger)*, respectively.

Comment: Interestingly, the official docs say **at no point** that a negative int actually means *this < that*. They just say that there are three distinct return values: a negative int, zero, and a positive int. One of them means *this < that*, one means *this > that* and one means *this == that*. Which is which, the docs do not specify at any point - in fact, you could say, the authors tried hard to write around that detail and leave it open.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I disagree. "Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer **as this object is** less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object." The "as this object is" part maps integers to relations.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd: I have always interpreted `compareTo` as you say, but now I'm finding myself in the situation of defending my assumption that things are as you say towards QA people who insist that the Java docs do not explicitly say "a negative integer means less than" etc. and thus any code that assumes so is incorrect. If there are any more explicit statements about that in the Java docs, I'd like to learn about them; I couldn't find any so far.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "and thus any code that assumes so is incorrect" ROFL! So the following are all incorrect: java.util.Tree(Map|Set), Collections.sort(), Arrays.sort() and many other places. Please! If you have to cope with guys like that then either they or you are in the wrong job.

Comment: In your warning you say "you should never rely on the return values of compareTo..." Why not? In what situations would compareTo yield something other than -1, 0, or 1?

Comment: @kojow I haven't come across such an implementation, but [the contract clearly says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-): "Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object."

Comment: @kowjow7 System.out.println("alpha".compareTo("deta")); yields -3

Answer (score 56):

I use this mnemonic :

```
a.compareTo(b) < 0 // a < b

a.compareTo(b) > 0 // a > b

a.compareTo(b) == 0 // a == b
```

You keep the signs and always compare the result of `compareTo()` to 0

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: I use this numeric-only version to remember easily: `a.compareTo(b) = a - b`.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten `a-b` should never be used in an implementation of compareTo() in real code, because it can (and will) overflow.

Answer (score 34):

Answer in short: (search your situation)

- **1**.compareTo(**0**) (*return*: **1**)
- **1**.compareTo(**1**) (*return*: **0**)
- **0**.comapreTo(**1**) (*return*: **-1**)

Answer (score 5):

take example if we want to compare "a" and "b", i.e ("a" == this)

1. negative int if a < b
2. if a == b
3. Positive int if a > b

Answer (score 3):

It can be used for sorting, and 0 means "equal" while -1, and 1 means "less" and "more (greater)".

Any return value that is less than 0 means that left operand is lesser, and if value is bigger than 0 then left operand is bigger.

Comment: It's negative, positive and 0, not simply -1, 1 and 0

Comment: Colin, there was -1, 0 and 1 in question. And yes, while some comparators return only one of those values, other can return any value, where negative means that left operand is smaller, zero means both operands are equal, and positive means left is bigger. Outside the Java land thats like `strcmp()` from C works.

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = thisObject.compareTo(anotherObject);
```

The `compareTo()` method returns an int with the following characteristics:

- negative `If thisObject < anotherObject`
- zero `If thisObject == anotherObject`
- positive `If thisObject > anotherObject`

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println(A.compareTo(B)>0?"Yes":"No")

if the value of A>B it will return "Yes" or "No".

Comment: Do you think your answer suits the question?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it