# Effective java Item no 5 example code second edition

Tags: java, object, effective-java

```
public class Person
private final Date  birthDate;
// others fields omitted
public  boolean isBabyBoomer() {
Calendar gmtCal =
Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
gmtCal.set(1946,Calendar.JANUARY,1,0,0,0);
Date boomStart =gmtCal.getTime();
gmtCal.set(1965,Calendar.JANUARY,1,0,0,0);
Date boomEnd = gmtCal.getTime();
return birthDate.compareTo(boomStart) >= 0 &&   //where is Birthdate instance 
                                                 // to compare                                   
birthDate.compareTo(boomEnd) < 0;

}
}
```

1. when and how the program gets birthdate instance ?
2. Do they omitted coding process for that instance ?
3. For what  purpose they compared results with zero(>= and < ) inside return ?
4. Can not we use simple return without using zeros integer (boolean only for testing) ?

Comment: The book assumes you can work these things out for yourself, so I suggest you try doing just that.  You can answer these questions without any additional information, there is no trick here.

Comment: A trickier question would be; proposes a different date for the `boomStart` and say why this might be better than using Jan 1st.

Comment: thank you peter ,can we write return as                                                             return  birthDate.compareTo(boomStart) && birthDate.compareTo(boomEnd) ;               without knowing how to set birthdate  it is hard for me to test(compile) .Anyone help to by writing the full code to get birthDate thank you

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3767090/113632) for a discussion of the `compareTo()` API.

Answer (score 0):

1. Given fact `birthDate` is final, i would say it is passed to class via constructor,
2. It is common practice in books and other tutorin materials to omit bits of code which are not relevant for given example to avoid creating extra confision for reader
3. Method `compareTo` returns `int` hence if you want to convert this to boolean result, you have to compare it to some number by using one of of the operators `==, !=, <, >, <=, >=`
4. And how you want to use simple return?