# What is mean by return 1, -1 and 0 ? What values does this method returns?

Tags: java, methods, return

/*
What values are return when I mention return 1, -1 and 0 in the method

I was writing thing this code to sort String based on there size
*/

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2)
{
    int len1 = s1.length();
    int len2 = s2.length();

    if(len1 > len2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (len1 < len2)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: look in your analysis and check there. 0 means that s1 and s2 have the same length, -1 means that s1 is longer compared to s2 and 1 means s2 is the longest of the two

Comment: The sign -1/0/1 = less/equal/greater; returns a comparison of the lengths

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the return values of Comparable.compareTo mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767090/what-do-the-return-values-of-comparable-compareto-mean-in-java)

Comment: Thanks i got it, basically yes it was 1 if s1 was greater, 0 if both are equal and -1 if s1 is smaller then s2. Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 3):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (for the Comparable interface) is pretty clear about the "generic" meaning of these 3 numbers:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

And -1, 0, 1 are simply ideal values to get you to that "less than 0, 0 and positive integer" part. So probably the method shown here is simply following that "contract".

Comment: indeed, but the code shown is not an implementation for Comparable. Comparable accepts one param, and has the method name compareTo

Comment: @Stultuske Indeed! I slightly reworded the initial sentence, it should make more sense now!